# Basic forum going to created topic

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am making a forum as a bit of practice.
But i have run into a problem.
When i create new question i want the page to go directly to that question.
But things like the id are made inside the database.
Maybe i need to change the structure of my database?
So how can i do this?

If you need anymore information please just ask.

Here is my query for inserting new questions

```
"INSERT INTO questions 
(title, description, username, date_made) 
VALUES 
('" . $title . "','" . $description . "', '".$usernameinsert."','".$a."')"
```

Comment: It is possible to retrieve the last inserted ID from the database, http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php, you can get the last inserted ID and then do a redirect to the page with that ID

Comment: for redirection, what did you try?

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia i tried making a point like id witch i could select and go to but then i got to this problem and tried google for an awnser

Comment: As Sythnet suggested use the last insert id and pass it to a redirection url as GET parameter. You can then use the id from url to get all the details for that question and display it's details on the redirected page

Comment: what problem can you explain...please

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia it seems that it has allready been solved :D thx guys if one of you would give it in an awnser i would gladly accept it

Comment: If you have any questions regarding edit, better ask

Comment: @YourCommonSense Not really just deleting

Comment: @smitty Johnson... Cheers then, but what was issue...

Comment: all right I'll revert it then

Comment: Seriously terrible question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to retrieve the last inserted ID from the database, [us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php), you can get the last inserted ID and then do a redirect to the page with that ID

Once you have the last ID, do a redirect to another page e.g. your forum page with the ID passed through, you can then use that ID on your page to display what you need to display (e.g. comments on the post)